# Why is this noun singular?

Tags: grammar

Why is the "performance" singular in "Analysis of authentication and identification performance" since it is basically the shortened of "Analysis of authentication performance and identification performance" so there are two performances?

Comment: Can you add some explanation of why you think it should not be singular?

Comment: Because there are two performances: authentication performance and identification performance.

Comment: Thanks - can you edit that in to your question?

Comment: I think that could explain. Thanks.

Comment: cf 'kitchen and bedroom furniture'. 'Furniture' is almost always seen and treated as a purely non-count noun (and displays the singular form), but is occasionally countified when speaking of major styles of furniture ('the very different furnitures of Louis XV and Louis XVI'). 'Performance' regularly appears in both non-count and count usages. Here, we see the non-count usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, [**performance**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/performance) is a mass (uncountable) noun.

The sentence has only *one* 'performance' anyway, with two of its aspects mentioned.

Comment: That's right. Two instances of a mass noun do not a count noun make. So even if you were comparing the performance of authentication against the performance of identification, you are still only comparing their performance not their "performances", something which occurs only when there are actual performers doing tricks on stage. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have almost answered your own question:

It is a title. It announces what is to follow.

In fact, it is the shortened version of "**What follows is the** analysis of authentication performance and **the analysis of** identification performance."

You will see that there are two main clauses joined by a coordinating conjunction.

In essence this does not differ from

"This is a black cat and this is a black dog", which, as a title, could be reduced to

"Black Dog and Cat"

Comment: Is it true also if the phrase is in the body of the text?

Comment: I have said: In essence this (i.e. your example) does not differ from "This is a black cat and this is a black dog",

Comment: @RezaYahyaei *What follows is the analysis [of the performance [of the authentication and of the identification]].*  So **an** analysis follows, not many analyses follow.

Comment: @Greybeard There are not two main clauses here separated by a conjunction. That is not correct. "What follows" constitutes an embedded clause whose verb is *follows*. The other clause is the one whose verb is *is*. No conjunction separates those two, nor should it, since you must not separate the subject from its predicate.

Comment: @tchrist *There are not two main clauses here* -- From the OP: **Because there are two performances: authentication performance and identification performance.**

Comment: There still aren't two clauses that way: "Analysis of authentication performance and identification performance" is not a clause, let alone two.

Comment: As per my answer: *it is the shortened version of "What follows is the analysis of authentication performance and the analysis of identification performance."*